# Close Bootstrap tab pane and remove active class from link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

There are some questions about this topic, but I can't find a solution for remove `.active` class from `.nav-link` when it's clicked. Here's what I tryed:

```
$('.nav-link').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#' + this.hash.substr(1).toLowerCase()).toggleClass('active');
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/marcelo-villela-gusm-o/pen/ZMOmoO?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stop the event from propagating. Use `return false` for that:

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdzXpw?editors=1010

JS:

```
 $('.nav-link.active').on('click', function(){
//This targets only li elements having active class
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#' + this.hash.substr(1).toLowerCase()).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot a simple part. But I can't use `$('.nav-link.active')` as a selector because `.active` is added dynamically after page load.

Comment: @marcelo2605 Ok. You can use old code as well. Just make sure you use return false;

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest another approach? Instead of using the click event, use the 'shown.bs.tab' event

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
})
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Did you this in my example code?

Comment: Yes, I have forked your sample: https://codepen.io/robledosm/pen/QVEzmp after clicking on the tab, the active class is being removed

Comment: Yes, but this must happen only if `.nav-link` already has class `.active`.